# Nodejs game checking players who are waiting to play

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need some guidance following a nodejs app I want to create.
It is a quiz game where 2 people will "fight" eachother answering 5 questions.
The problem is that I don't know how can I implement the "state" of the users which are waiting to find an opponent.

Is there a module that I can use which will save the state of the users in a table and then will put them both in the same "room" for playing? Or how should I think about achieving this?

I'm thinking about something like this:

1. A user clicks the PLAY button
2. I'll save the user ID in a table
3. When another user clicks the PLAY button, I'll save it's ID in the same row as the previous user who is waiting for an opponent.
4. I'll put them both on the same game ( I'm not very sure how to do this either...)

Any guidance would be really helpful. For more informations about what I want to achieve check out mathfights.com where you can see the example I am talking about.

Comment: are you using socketio or a similar websocket library?

Comment: Yes. I'm going to use socket.io

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array or a set(ES6) with all the users that are waiting for a match, let's say you call it waitingList. When a user clicks play button you push his socket in the waitingList. Then you iterate through the waitingList to find a possible match based on user's lever,score etc... After that you have 2 or more sockets(players) that can go in a match, simply you remove them from the waitingList and you send them to your game logic.Of course this solution is based on in memory saves. for example if your server crashes or restarts you will lose all the running games, i dont know if that matters you right now but you could use redis or a similar database to solve that sometime in future.

Comment: Can I use mysql to save all the games in it? And then I'll remove the players that finished the game and put them in another table.

Comment: of course you can use mysql but it's kind of overkill. a simple array would be easier to implement and faster. I believe the only reason you want mysql is because you feel comfortable with it and not with writing javascript logic?

Comment: It's because I'm using it for the whole application. And I also want to save all the game results into mysql. But if you say it's better, I might think of using javascript logic. How would that look like in your opinion?